Unable to read file using fs.readFile in node.js
My folder structure is like this.
src
  |html
  |generate.js

I am trying to generate the text folder same as html folder under src by reading the files in html. For example, if a.html and b.html is under html folder, i want to generate a.txt and b.txt files under text folder by reading the a.html and b.html files.
The script in generate.js is below.
const fs = require("fs");
const filesArray = ['html/a.html', 'html/b.html'];

filesArray.forEach((item) => {
     fs.readFile(item, (err, data) => {
       console.log(item, data);
     });
});

when I print data within fs.readfile function, it returns undefined.
And when I try to print the error, getting the below error.
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myname\projectRepo\src\html\a.html'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\projectRepo\\src\\html\\a.html'
}

I am running 'node generate.js' command to run the above script.

I can't reproduce this problem (node 20.10.0). I get the array string, and the data. Note I imported fs which you don't show in your example but I assume that you're doing that?

So why don’t you print out the err what is the most interesting in this case?

I am getting the below error @Thallius
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myname\projectRepo\src\html\a.html'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\myname\projectRepo\src\html\a.html'
}

I am using node version of 20.2.0 @Andy

Well, the error message is quite clear: The file you are trying to read does not exist. So either you are looking for your file in the wrong location, or you forgot to create the files in that location

@derpirscher But it exists. That is the problem. Is there a problem the way i use the file path?

No it doesn't. If fs fails with a NOENT it's quite safe to assume the file doesn't exist, and it doesn't make sense to insist, the file does exist. Check the spelling of the path and filename. Check also if the complete path from the error meets your expectations of the path where your files (allegedly) are located.

Backslashes in patches are always a very bad idea… even windows has detected that after a plenty of years :)

@Thallius There are no backslashes in the (visbile) source. But node typically formats filenames and paths according to the format of the OS it is running on ...

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. It's not confirmed that C:\Users\myname\projectRepo\src\html\a.html exists. Just insisting that it doesn't work the way you describe won't help to solve it. Also it's universally a bad idea to rely on relative paths as they depend on CWD. Use path.join(__dirname, ...) for files that are relative to a project
